# Disable date before current date in jquery and input is in user control and user control is in update pannel

Tags: jquery, asp.net, updatepanel, jquery-ui-datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I tried a lot for user not able to select previous date but then also its not working below is the code for was tried for the same but 
i am using Bootstrap Datepicker  v1.4.1

Below is the code for usercontrol.ascx code

```
     <asp:UpdatePanel ID="mainUpdate" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 form-row">
      <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_deadline" runat="server" ToolTip="Enter your deadline in days" ClientIDMode="Static" ValidationGroup="ordernow" CssClass="form-control date-picker" placeholder="Deadline : dd/mm/yy"></asp:TextBox>              
  </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And script code before closing body tag is

```
<script> 
        function pageLoad() {
            var date_input = $('input[name="NewCostCalculator1$TextBox_deadline"]'); //our date input has the name "date"
            var container = $('.bootstrap-iso form').length > 0 ? $('.bootstrap-iso form').parent() : "body";
            date_input.datepicker({
                format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
                container: container,
                todayHighlight: true,
                autoclose: true,
                orientation: "left bottom",
                minDate: 0,
            })

        } 
    </script>
```

after click on textbox datepicker looks like below please help me...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

below code works for me if any suggestions please tell me...

```
 <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

                function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
                    var date_input = $('input[name="NewCostCalculator1$TextBox_deadline"]'); //our date input has the name "date"
                    var container = $('.bootstrap-iso form').length > 0 ? $('.bootstrap-iso form').parent() : "body";
                    date_input.datepicker({
                        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
                        container: container,
                        todayHighlight: true,
                        autoclose: true,
                        orientation: "left bottom",
                        startDate: new Date(),
                    });
                }
                var date_input = $('input[name="NewCostCalculator1$TextBox_deadline"]'); //our date input has the name "date"
                var container = $('.bootstrap-iso form').length > 0 ? $('.bootstrap-iso form').parent() : "body";
                date_input.datepicker({
                    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
                    container: container,
                    todayHighlight: true,
                    autoclose: true,
                    orientation: "left bottom",
                    startDate: new Date(),

                });
            });



        </script>
```